# linux sever interfaces automation

Tags: linux, centos, linux-networking, linux-kernel

I am using a CentOS server which has about 6 active interfaces with different IPs, I'd want to automatically bring down all the interfaces when any one of the 6 interfaces is down. Is there a way this can be done?

I've been trying to find a method to do this, but so far failed.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How do you define down?  Is it loss of link on the cable connecting to the interface, or some kind of upstream loss?

Comment: I'll say its a loss of link on the cable connecting to the interface..

Comment: You might want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261759/get-notified-about-network-interface-change-on-linux) to get started.

Comment: If you bring down _all_ the network interfaces, you'll have to have some way to bring them back up later.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Monit](http://mmonit.com/). You can configure it to monitor your network connections and have it act when a failure is detected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **NetworkManager**: NM automatically executes scripts found in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` every time any interface changes its status (see `man NetworkManager`). You can write a script to manually bring down the other interfaces and put the script in the `dispatcher.d/`. NM passes 2 arguments to scripts found in the `dispatcher.d/` , the **name** of the device and the **action** (whether an interface is brought `up`  or `down`, again see NM manual for exact key words). So your script should only bring down the other interfaces if the 2nd argument is down.

If you aren't using NetworkManager, there's a software called **ifplugd** which might help you. However, this software is quite old. Last update was on 2005.

Comment: I wouldn't want to use NetworkManager if I can avoid it (too many bad experiences previously).. although I'll give this a shot.. 

and just thinking out loud here, how about using 'ifup' and 'ifdown' within a script?.. is this something I can explore?

Comment: You can put a script in /var/run/netreport and this script will run when you deactivate an interface manually, ie ifdown eth1. I don't know of an automatic way to do this. I think you have to have some daemon running in the background that will let you know that an interface has been brought down. Besides NM, I don't know if a default CentOS installation already has that already.